# Creating a checkout session with a non-zero unit_amount_decimal returns an error message of a deprecated amount field

Tags: stripe-payments

I seem to be experiencing an odd response behaviour from stripe when trying to create a checkout session if my unit_amount_decimal has a value of anything other than zero after the decimal.

Running this in postman (I've just replaced the key and urls for this example) where the unit_amount_decimal is 23.99 will give me an error response to do with a deprecated ([according to their documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create)) 'amount' field even though I'm not using that field in my POST:

```
POST /v1/checkout/sessions HTTP/1.1
Host: api.stripe.com
Authorization: Bearer sk_test_mytestenvironmentsecretkey
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

success_url=https://example.com/payment/success&cancel_url=https://example.com/payment/cancel&payment_method_types[0]=card&mode=subscription&line_items[0][quantity]=1&line_items[0][price_data][currency]=USD&line_items[0][price_data][product]=prod_HoG79Vj0HStdtG&line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount_decimal]=23.99&line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval]=day&line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval_count]=1&customer=cus_HoG7QB7kstWaWB
```

Response from Stripe will be:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Checkout does not support plans with more than 2 decimals in the `amount` in `line_items[0]`.",
    "param": "line_items[0]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

If I do the same POST but change the unit_amount_decimal value to 23.00 / 23.0 / 23 for example, it's happy with the request and responds with a checkout session object:

```
POST /v1/checkout/sessions HTTP/1.1
Host: api.stripe.com
Authorization: Bearer sk_test_mytestenvironmentsecretkey
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

success_url=https://example.com/payment/success&cancel_url=https://example.com/payment/cancel&payment_method_types[0]=card&mode=subscription&line_items[0][quantity]=1&line_items[0][price_data][currency]=USD&line_items[0][price_data][product]=prod_HoG79Vj0HStdtG&line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount_decimal]=23.00&line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval]=day&line_items[0][price_data][recurring][interval_count]=1&customer=cus_HoG7QB7kstWaWB
```

Response from Stripe:

```
{
  "id": "cs_test_9FDuAIEyGuvb9RapQ0pOAs4240UHRhSqks1kezHYBhEaBX5tG59mOBqB",
  "object": "checkout.session",
  "allow_promotion_codes": null,
  "amount_subtotal": 23,
  "amount_total": 23,
  "billing_address_collection": null,
  "cancel_url": "https://example.com/payment/cancel",
  "client_reference_id": null,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_HoG7QB7kstWaWB",
  "customer_email": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "locale": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "mode": "subscription",
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "setup_intent": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "shipping_address_collection": null,
  "submit_type": null,
  "subscription": null,
  "success_url": "https://example.com/payment/success",
  "total_details": {
    "amount_discount": 0,
    "amount_tax": 0
  }
}
```

I've read the [documentation around decimals amounts](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/decimal-amounts) but haven't seen a reason why it wouldn't like a decimal amount with something other than a zero value after the decimal.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing incorrectly here? It doesn't make sense for me to be creating price objects before this POST in my scenario so I'm hoping I can just use this price_data to create a price object inline [as their documentation suggests](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create)

Comment: I misread the documentation for decimal values - it's still for defining the minor unit (such as cents) which means me passing 23.99 still means 23.99 cents rather than $23.99 which is what I thought. But it does seem like this unit_amount_decimal field should allow for up to 12 decimal places.

Comment: Looks to be a bug, you should contact Stripe support at https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score 4):

I misread the documentation for decimal values - it's still for defining the minor unit (such as cents) which means me passing 23.99 still means 23.99 pence rather than £23.99 which is what I thought.

I've contacted Stripe support and they responded to say they don't support Prices with sub-cent amounts in Checkout (which is understandable). They have raised the issue and will be updating the documentation so the session object doesn't include the unit_amount_decimal property.